# What are the best practices in automating end 2 end testcases?

Tags: java, testing, automation, frameworks, e2e

I am trying to get a clear understanding of what e2e test cases look like.
And I am confused about how e2e testing is handled by companies. In my understanding, e2e testing is the testing of different systems and layers of the application. An example: if I am trying to e2e test a "purchase" endpoint I would have to also check the DB layer and do a purchase flow using UI. Please correct me if I am wrong.
SO the questing is - How would I automate this type of scenario? Do I test UI, API, and DB separately or do I write a huge test case? Also if my automation framework only handles API and DB layers. I am even able to create an e2e test case if I don't test the Web Layer?

Comment: It's not end-to-end if it skips one end.

Comment: There are no best practices.  It depends on what suits >your< requirements.

Comment: It's common to start your entire application and perform operations via a browser, using e.g. selenium. You will probably want scaffolding to allow you to load specific states into the DB (which may also involve clearing caches in your application) and "backdoors" to perform operations which take many UI steps (e.g. creating multiple test users) and to verify backend state (if that is hard to do via the UI).